# d3 force layout snap to grid on drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, snapping

How do you snap to a grid after dragging is finished in d3?

I tried adding an event listener to the `dragend` event and rounding the values, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
force.drag()
    .on('dragend', function(d) {
        d.fixed = false;
        d.x = Math.round(d.x / 10) * 10;
        d.y = Math.round(d.y / 10) * 10;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zc89zj9e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're 2 issues with your jsfiddle. First, the nodes become undraggable once they have been dragged -- this is because you set `d.fixed = true` on `dragend`. This prevents any further position changes. The solution is to set `d.fixed = false` on `dragstart`.

Second, in addition to `d.x` and `d.y`, you need to set `d.px` and `d.py` (which the force layout uses internally) for the position change to take effect.

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  // ...
  d.fixed = false;
}

function dragended(d) {
  d.fixed = true;
  d.x = d.px = Math.round(d.x / 100) * 100;
  d.y = d.py = Math.round(d.y / 100) * 100;
}
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zc89zj9e/1/).